# Is there a downside of using PCB printed USB connector?

Tags: pcb-design, usb, certification

Typical USB Type A receptacle is as shown in this image from Molex  48037-1000, which can be mounted on PCB.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I have seen some products with USB connectors printed directly on the PCB edge like this UMFT201XB:

[image]

Is there a downside to using PCB printed USB connectors? Does losing shield affect ESD performance, durability, certification? Does it make difference if I am using this connector in laptop USB port vs DC wall adapter?

Comment: my mistake on first image, i should have shown male connector in both images

Comment: The gold plating may not be very thick if the manufacturer used a cheap ENIG process, so it will wear through after very few insertions.

Comment: Show the actual interface physical connections you want to use at USB2. Yes , you would want more than 2u” flash gold for contacts

Comment: I agree with thicker copper or gold fingers but I am more concern about missing shield and its effect.

Comment: Mechanical yanking and bending of the PCB-made connector can flex part of the rest of the PCB. So it may make the PCB assembly more susceptible to damage than with the proper connector. It's also true that the connector can be replaced when damaged to rescue the PCB, unlike the PCB-made one, but only a miniscule percentage of the damaged USB connectors out there ever get replaced so that's not a factor.

Answer (score 1):

> Does losing shield affect ESD performance, durability, certification

Yes on all three counts:

ESD:  the shroud also gives some protection, this is better if the shroud covers the whole circuit, not just the connector, or if some other structure coves the remainder of the circuit.

Durability: exposed board fibres will cause greater wear on the socket than will using the correct connector. Made from polyester resin and glass fibre the substrate of the board will attack the gold plating to a larger extent than the slick plastic used in the manufacture of approved A plugs.

However the one piece printed connector design is tougher than the two part solder-attached plug, but this may be a mixed blessing: adverse forces that would have broken the two part assembly may now damage the host instead.

Certification: without the shroud you won't meet the minimum unmating force requirement, and probably several others required for approval.

> Does it make difference if I am using this connector in laptop USB port vs DC wall adapter?

Yes, in a DC wall adaptor the shield does much less electrically , and with a lower replacement cost, the risk of increased wear and equipment damage is less significant.

Comment: I think forces that would break the two-part assembly are likely to just break the circuit board. Remember the host's socket still has a metal shroud around it and the device's plug doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a downside of using PCB printed USB connector?

If a USB cable is used, yes. Otherwise, no.

> Does losing shield affect ESD performance, durability, certification?

It shouldn't. The shield of the connector is more helpful when there is a USB cable.

> Does it make difference if I am using this connector in laptop USB port vs DC wall adapter?

Again, depends on the presence of a USB cable.

Comment: Sorry updated the question both should have neem USB plugs. So no cable, product will be inserted in either laptop receptacle or wall adapter receptacle.

Comment: @CuriousKP Can you rule out your user using a USB *extension* cable, for example to make your product more reachable or easily plugged/unplugged to a hard-to-reach PC (e.g. one locked in a cabinet, under a desk, integrated as a point of sale system, etc)?

Comment: Yes I can rule that out. But if at all user uses extension cable what is downside? Cable receptacle and laptop receptacle should be same.

Comment: @CuriousKP USB full-speed signalling requires a proper shielded cable, and a low-impedance connection between the cable's shield and the receptacle's shell (i.e. outer metal case). Using your circuit with an ext cable may not comply the EMI requirement, but probably don't affect the signal transmission.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @RohatKılıç